# Do all people upto Dwaparyuga believed in god ? What is the difference between Kaliyuga and other Yugas with regards to belief in god?

Tags: yuga, dwapara-yuga

In Kaliyuga , there are many people who don't believe in god and his power.

Was it true for other previous Yugas as well ?

Do all people in Satyuga, Treta Yuga and Dwaparyug believed in god and his power ? I think it can be true as in these three Yugas , visit of gods and avatars was common. Gods and devtas like - Brahma, Indra etc would frequently visit the earth (and would be seen by common people) on many occasion as written in Puranas.

Eg- Indra visited Vrindavan when he was causing heavy rain there and directly gave darshan to all people.

Krisha would show his god form in Vrindavan during Raasleela and all gopis and other people knew he was god.

So, I think people living in Dwaparyuga would easily be believing in god and his power.

**What is the difference between Kaliyuga and other Yugas with regards to belief in god ?**